# Binding a relay command from a class to a CustomCommand mismatching

Tags: maui, mvvm-toolkit

I am making a ribbon like menu.

For achieving, I created three basic components.

- Component Item Class
- Menu Template (XAML)
- Menu Template (Code Behind)

The class define each item

```cs
public class MenuComponentItems {

    public string ImageSource { get; set; }

    public string CommandParameter { get; set; }

    public string Section { get; set; }

    public IRelayCommand Command { get; set; }

}
```

then we will define the UI

```xml
<Border
    Margin="5,5,0,0"
    HeightRequest="120"
    VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <Grid
        RowSpacing="5"
        VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <HorizontalStackLayout
            x:Name="MenuItemsStack"
            BackgroundColor="Bisque" />

        <Label
            Grid.Row="1"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding SectionName, Source={x:Reference MenuComponent}}" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

and finally, the code behind of the control

```cs
public partial class MenuTemplate : ContentView {

public ObservableCollection<MenuComponentItems> MenuItems { get; set; } = [];

public MenuTemplate() {
        InitializeComponent();
        MenuItems.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => UpdateMenu();
}

public static readonly BindableProperty SectionNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(SectionName),
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MenuTemplate));

public string SectionName {
    get => (string)GetValue(SectionNameProperty);
    set => SetValue(SectionNameProperty, value);
}

private void UpdateMenu() {
    MenuItemsStack.Children.Clear();

    foreach (var menuItem in MenuItems) {
        var imageButton = new ImageButton {
            Source = menuItem.ImageSource,
            WidthRequest = 60,
            HeightRequest = 60,
            Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 10, 0),
            Command = menuItem.Command,
            CommandParameter = menuItem.CommandParameter
        };

        MenuItemsStack.Children.Add(imageButton);
    }
}
```

usage

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="200, *">
    <HorizontalStackLayout>
        <controls:MenuTemplate SectionName="ferwqfkrew">
            <controls:MenuTemplate.MenuItems>
                <models:MenuComponentItems
                    ImageSource="dotnet_bot.png"
                    Section="Section 1" />
                <models:MenuComponentItems
                    ImageSource="mario.png"
                    Section="Section 1" />
            </controls:MenuTemplate.MenuItems>
        </controls:MenuTemplate>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</Grid>
```

output

[image: output]

**Problem**

when I create a relay command in my view model

```cs
[RelayCommand]
public void MenuItemSelected(object param) {
    
    Debug.WriteLine("dcd");
}
```

and bind it I get

property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Command", or mismatching.

What I do not, is the fact that in my class I have a RelayCommand and my vm is a RelayCommand as well.

At first, I thought that is because a ImageButton command is an ICommand and not a RelayCommand, but I tested an ImageButton with the same command and it triggered

**Thing that I tried**

1. Using ICommand instead of the RelayCommand of the Microsoft mvvm toolkit
2. Created a RelayCommand property in the control itself

**Update**

I made my class inherit form ContentView

```cs
public class MenuComponentItems : ContentView {

    public string ImageSource { get; set; }

    public string CommandParameter { get; set; }


    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Command), typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(MenuComponentItems));

    public RelayCommand Command {
        get => (RelayCommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't trigger the command.

**Usage**

```cs
public class MenuComponentItems : ContentView {

public string ImageSource { get; set; }

public string CommandParameter { get; set; }


public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Command), typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(MenuTemplate));

public RelayCommand Command {
    get => (RelayCommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
    set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
}
```

```xml
<controls:MenuTemplate SectionName="ferwqfkrew">
    <controls:MenuTemplate.MenuItems>
        <models:MenuComponentItems Command="{Binding MenuItemSelectedCommand}"
            ImageSource="dotnet_bot.png" />
```

```cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject {
     
    [RelayCommand]
    public void MenuItemSelected() {
    
        Debug.WriteLine("dcd");
    }
}
```

I inspected the `MenuItemsStack.Children.Add(imageButton);` and for some reason the command is null.

I tested it with a button, and it works, so the VM is fine, the problem is the custom control that doesn't get the command

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Where is the binding where you use the command?

Comment: Can you try putting your `new ImageButton` in a `try ... catch` to see where it raises an exception ? Also, shouldn't your `MenuComponentItems` inherit from `ContentView` as well ?

Comment: I cant put it the try catch, because it would say anything, because it add the item, the problem is the command. by the way, why should my  `MenuComponentItems` inherit from `Contentview`

Comment: So when is the error raised exactly ? It adds the item without any problem ? Is it when you call the command ?

Comment: And I'm not sure about the ContentView inheritance, it was a random suggestion but I'm not sure it is really mandatory. Was still worth a try ahah

Comment: Well I added what you told me, and fixe it, but it dosent triget the command

Comment: I inspected the command and is null, but why

Comment: Can you provide exactly how you bind a specific command to your item ? In your "usage" code there is no mention of the command. Also, in one of my project I use a command in a custom control, the same way you do in your `MenuComponentItems` with a BindableProperty, except I use `ICommand` instead of `RelayCommand`.

Comment: I edit it and gave you more context

Comment: Let's continue in [a discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257266/discussion-between-gchapx-and-natash-dimas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after trying several things, I actually found a workaround for your situation : it seems no Command was called because when generating your `ImageButtons`, the `BindingContext` of `MenuComponentItems` was null.

The workaround :

- Set your `UpdateMenu` method to public and update BindingContext when iterating :

```cs
public void UpdateMenu() {
    MenuItemsStack.Children.Clear();

    foreach (var menuItem in MenuItems) {
        menuItem.BindingContext = this.BindingContext; // Somehow the MenuTemplate's BindingContext is correct, only item's one isn't set, we fix this here.
        var imageButton = new ImageButton {
            Source = menuItem.ImageSource,
            WidthRequest = 60,
            HeightRequest = 60,
            Command = menuItem.Command,
            CommandParameter = menuItem.CommandParameter
        };

        MenuItemsStack.Children.Add(imageButton);
    }
}
```

- In your `View`, give a Name to your control, and after setting the `BindingContext` of the view and initializing the component, call `UpdateMenu` to force the Binding :

```cs
public MainPage(MainViewModel mainViewModel) {
    BindingContext = mainViewModel;
    InitializeComponent();
    YourMainTemplate.UpdateMenu();
}
```

Not gonna lie, I'm still not sure what the issue is and why this approach works, but at least now it calls your Command !

Answer (score 0):

I also found a solution.

```cs
private void UpdateMenu() {
    MenuItemsStack.Children.Clear();

    foreach (var menuItem in MenuItems) {
        var imageButton = new ImageButton {
            Source = menuItem.ImageSource,
            WidthRequest = 60,
            HeightRequest = 60,
        };

        imageButton.SetBinding(ImageButton.CommandProperty, new Binding("MenuItemSelectedCommand"));

        Binding parameter = new() {
        Source = imageButton
    };
    imageButton.SetBinding(ImageButton.CommandParameterProperty, parameter);

    MenuItemsStack.Children.Add(imageButton);
}
```

You just need to call `relayCommand` of your `viewModel`.